# How to use nested objects with dynamic keys in schema in Mongoose NestJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, schema

I have the schemas

```
// this is collection schema

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop()
  age: number;

  @Prop()
  role: string;

  @Prop(/* ???????? */)
  info: Record<string, Info>;
}


//this is schema of nested object
@Schema()
export class Info {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  surname: string;
}
```

I want to keep data like in this format:

```
{
  age: 20,
  role: 'user',
  info: {
    en: {
      name: 'John'
      surname: 'Smith'
    },
    fr: {
      name: 'Johny'
      surname: 'La`Smith'
    },
  }
}
```

so: `en`, `fr`, etc... is language name (this fields are **dynamic**, there are can be a lot of languages)

**How to implement this on schema??**
(what should be in Prop() info field???)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
@Prop({ type: Map, of: SchemaTypes.Mixed })
info: Record<string, Info>;
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps

I did it differently

```
export interface IMeta {
    [index: string]: string | number | boolean | object | undefined;
}

@Prop({ type: Map })
meta: IMeta;
```

`[index: string]: string` its Index Signatures for universal description of probable data.